# JBoss Developer Studio 11.0.0GA Date Transform Problems

Tags: redhat, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio, data-transform

I'm trying to create a simple Fuse Integration Project which should transform input message message in XML format to output message in XML format.

For developing i'm using Jboss Fuse Developer Studio 11.0.0GA with integration-stack.

I'm using to XSD schemas and Date Transform node for it.

The first XSD schema **schema_1.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Message" type="Message_Type">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Message_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The second schema **schema_2.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="MyMessage" type="MyMessage_Type">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="MyMessage_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

After i choose this schemas (as source and target type) the studio generate:

- Java classes **MessageType.java** and **ObjectFactory.java** in **generated_1521205138227** package
- Java classes **MyMessageType.java** and **ObjectFactory.java** in **generated_1521205139146** package

When i'm trying to open **transformation.xml** file i have an error **Faild to create the part's controls** and Exception with text below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: generated_1521205138226.MessageType
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.core.dozer.DozerMapperConfiguration.loadModel(DozerMapperConfiguration.java:435)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.core.dozer.DozerMapperConfiguration.getSourceModel(DozerMapperConfiguration.java:382)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.editor.internal.util.TransformationManager.rootSourceModel(TransformationManager.java:196)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.editor.internal.SourceTabFolder.<init>(SourceTabFolder.java:44)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.editor.TransformationEditor.createPartControl(TransformationEditor.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:955)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.editor.wizards.NewTransformationWizard$1.run(NewTransformationWizard.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:980)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.editor.wizards.NewTransformationWizard.performFinish(NewTransformationWizard.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.extensions.DataMapperEndpointFigureFeature.createNode(DataMapperEndpointFigureFeature.java:50)
    at org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor.features.create.ext.CreateFigureFeature.create(CreateFigureFeature.java:366)
    at org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor.features.create.ext.CreateEndpointFigureFeature.create(CreateEndpointFigureFeature.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.features.impl.AbstractCreateFeature.execute(AbstractCreateFeature.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.internal.command.GenericFeatureCommandWithContext.execute(GenericFeatureCommandWithContext.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.internal.command.GFPreparableCommand.doExecute(GFPreparableCommand.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand.execute(RecordingCommand.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.editor.GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.execute(GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.internal.command.CommandExec.executeCommand(CommandExec.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.command.CreateModelObjectCommand.execute(CreateModelObjectCommand.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.editor.EmfOnGefCommand.execute(EmfOnGefCommand.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.internal.command.GFPreparableCommand2.doExecute(GFPreparableCommand2.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand.execute(RecordingCommand.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.EMFCommandOperation.doExecute(EMFCommandOperation.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.AbstractEMFOperation.execute(AbstractEMFOperation.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.DefaultOperationHistory.execute(DefaultOperationHistory.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.impl.WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.doExecute(WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.editor.GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.execute(GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.editor.GFCommandStack.execute(GFCommandStack.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCommand(AbstractTool.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCurrentCommand(AbstractTool.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.gef.tools.CreationTool.performCreation(CreationTool.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.gef.tools.CreationTool.handleButtonUp(CreationTool.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.mouseUp(AbstractTool.java:1200)
    at org.eclipse.gef.EditDomain.mouseUp(EditDomain.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.DomainEventDispatcher.dispatchMouseReleased(DomainEventDispatcher.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.draw2d.LightweightSystem$EventHandler.mouseUp(LightweightSystem.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: generated_1521205138226.MessageType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.fuse.transformation.core.dozer.DozerMapperConfiguration.loadModel(DozerMapperConfiguration.java:432)
    ... 133 more
```

So, how it's possible to solve this problem?

P.s. When i'm using schemas with only one root element i have no this problem. Also, when i'm trying to use xml instance file for creating mapping i have **Unexpected error: null** with **NullPointerException**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue on Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 11.0.0.GA (JBoss Fuse Tooling Data Transformation 10.0.0.v20170724-0737) on a project based on **Spring DSL** (Blueprint projects works well).

Anyway, try to develop your application with the latest version of Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 11.2.0.GA (https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/download/). With this version, I was unable to reproduce your issue even with a project based on Spring DSL.